# Pandas: How to filter column list by value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas DataFrame that stores lists in one of its columns:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> d = [{'name': 'john', 'properties': ['a','b']},
...      {'name': 'mary', 'properties': ['a','c']}]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(d)
>>> df
   name properties
0  john     [a, b]
1  mary     [a, c]
```

How can I filter by list membership? For example, list all rows that have a 'c' in their *properties* column.

I know I could explode the *properties* column:

```
df.explode('properties')
```

but I'd prefer to keep it as a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map`.

```
df[df.properties.map(lambda x: 'c' in x)]
```